# htaccess multilanguage site

Tags: .htaccess, multilingual

hello all and thanks for any tip/info you will provide
we have a static site with about 100 pages (html) in English
now we upgrade this to be part dynamic and in 3 languages
what we think of doing is:

in English version: `/path/to/page.html`
in other versions: `/language/path/to/page.html`

tha actual content is served in both cases by a single php file, something like `page.php?lang=english` or `page.php?lang=french`

A general rewrite rule looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^/path/to/page.html$ page.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

My problem is i don't know how to modify this rule based on `$lang`.
So, if `$lang=english` OR `if $lang=''`, rule will be tanslated into `/path/to/page.html`

In all other lases rule will be `$lang/path/to/page.html`


Can this be accomplished by htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

First of all it might be best to have one set of content, not duplicated content for each langauge (If I understand you correctly.

We have multiple languages on our website (at work) and we store the translations in a database, then load the appropriate one for the language selected.

But if that way works well for you then you can ignore this :)

I've done something like this that might help:

```
# Force English
# for http://www.website.com/
RewriteRule ^$ page.php?lang=EN

# English
# for http://www.website.com/EN/
RewriteRule ^EN/?$ page.php?lang=EN

# Other Languages
# for http://www.website.com/DE/ etc
RewriteRule ^(DE|FR|ES)/?$ $1/path/to/page.php?lang=$1
```

Comment: are these rules correct?
don't you have multiple rewrites based on the first 2 rules?

Comment: Yes there are correct. The first rule is for when a language isn't passed, so it defaults to english, the second is for when a language is passed.